# PHP com PDO retorna data por extenso do SQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo, data

Tenho uma aplicação PHP que lê dados de tabelas que podem ser SQL ou Postgres.

Quando passei a utilizar PDO em vez do mssql, os campos data do SQL retornam por extenso ex: `'Nov 29 2019 12:00:00:AM'`. Se fizer a query diretamente no servidor obtenho '2019-11-29' ou se a chamada for ao postgres o resultado é o mesmo.

O campo SQL é do tipo 'date' apenas.

```
// Ligar a base de dados com PDO
class Conexao
{
    private static $connection;

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function getConnection() {

        $pdoConfig  = $_SESSION["bd_tipo"] . ":". "host=" . $_SESSION["bd_host"] . ";";
        $pdoConfig .= "dbname=".$_SESSION["bd_nome"].";";

        try {
            if(!isset($connection)){
                $connection =  new PDO($pdoConfig, $_SESSION["bd_user"], $_SESSION["bd_senha"]);
                $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            return $connection;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $mensagem = "Drivers disponiveis: " . implode(",", PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
            $mensagem .= "\nErro: " . $e->getMessage();
            throw new Exception($mensagem);
        }
    }
```

E para chamar:

```
$SQL = "SELECT TOP 30 * FROM assistencias WHERE id_tec=$id_tec order by 'data' DESC, 'id_assis' DESC";

try{
    $Conexao    = Conexao::getConnection();
    $query      = $Conexao->query($SQL);
    $result   = $query->fetchAll();

} catch(Exception $e){
          echo $e->getMessage();
          exit;
}
```

Necessito que a data esteja no formato `'2019-11-29'`. Já tentei o `date()` sem sucesso. Estou a utilizar o PHP 5.6.

Comment: Não é interessante pra você formatar essa data, por exemplo ` date('Y-m-d', strtotime('November 29, 2019, 12:00:00am')) `

Comment: Experimentei, não funcionou. Coloca todas as datas iguais: '1970-01-01'

Answer (score 1):

**Utilize a função:**

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate);
```

**Output:**

```
02-12-2019
```

**Para substituir** *"-"* **por** *"/"* **utilize**:

```
$date = "02-12-2019";
$date = str_replace("-", "/", $date);
```

[Referencia strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

[Referencia str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Na base de dados a data está no formato "2019-02-12" ao ler fica "Dec  2 2019 12:00:00:AM" e se utilizar o date resulta numa string vazia.

Comment: vc está usando Sql ou MySql?